# Using Ruby to solve a quiz

Tags: ruby

So I found this quiz on a website that I was excited to solve with my newly acquired Ruby skills (CodeAcademy, not quite finished yet).

What I want to do is make an array with 100 entries, all set to "open". Then, I planned to create a method containing a for loop that iterates through every nth entry of the array and changes it to either "open" or "closed", based on what it was before. In the for loop, n should be increased from 1 to 100.

What I have so far is this:

```
change_state = Proc.new { |element| element == "open" ? element = "closed" : element = "open" }

def janitor(array,n)
    for i in 1..n
        array.each { |element| if array.index(element) % i == 0 then element.change_state end }
    end
end

lockers = [*1..100]

lockers = lockers.map{ |element| element = "closed" }

result = janitor(lockers,100)
```

When trying to execute I receive an error saying:

```
undefined method `change_state' for "closed":String (NoMethodError)
```

Anybody an idea what is wrong here? I kinda think I'm calling the "change_state" proc incorrectly on the current array element.

If you know the quiz, no spoilers please!

Comment: Is this quiz for a class, or more of a problem set found online (like Project Euler)?

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong, you're using `for` and `each`, which is kind of twice of the same thing. Avoid `for` in Ruby.

Comment: `change_state` is a `Proc` so you should call it like `change_state.call(element)`. To do that you should make it visible to the code inside the `janitor` method .

Comment: And your Proc tries to change the string as if it were a reference, which it can't.

Comment: Read about procs and how to use them - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html

Comment: Yeah, that's not how a proc works. You don't need one here, what you need is a lookup table: `STATE_INVERSE = { open: :closed, closed: :open }` Then something like `element.state = STATE_INVERSE[element.state]`. Ideally you're using symbols instead of strings as that usually proves to be far more efficient.

Comment: This "project" is neither for a class nor from Project Euler. I read an article on an ordinary website that had a quiz for their readers. But since I couldn't figure out the solution in my head and I'm too lazy to do all the math I thought this could be an interesting excercise for me. This is just a hobby, never had any classes or so. Thanks for the input :) I'll try to fight myself through this!

Answer (score 3):

As you have implemented `change_state`, it is not a method of any class, and definitely not one attached  to any of the individual elements of the array, despite you using the same variable name `element`. So you cannot call it as `element.change_state`.

Instead, it is a variable pointing to a `Proc` object.

To call the code in a `Proc` object, you would use the `call` method, and  syntax like `proc_obj.call( params )` - in your case `change_state.call( element )`

If you just drop in that change, your error message will change to:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `change_state' for main:Object
```

That's because the `change_state` variable is not in scope inside the method, in order to be called. There are lots of ways to make it available. One option would be to pass it in as a parameter, so your definition for janitor becomes

```
 def janitor(array,n,state_proc)
```

(use the variable name `state_proc` inside your routine instead of `change_state` - I am suggesting you change the name to avoid confusing yourself)

You could then call it like this:

```
result = janitor(lockers,100,change_state)
```

Although your example does not really need this structure, this is one way in which Ruby code can provide a generic "outer" function - working through the elements of an array, say - and have the user of that code provide a small internal custom part of it. A more common way to achieve the same result as your example is to use a Ruby block and the `yield` method, but `Proc`s also have their uses, because you can treat them like data as well as code - so you can pass them around, put them into hashes or arrays to decide which one to call etc.

There may be other issues to address in your code, but this is the cause of the error message in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This indeed fixed the error message, however now my method returns an array with the numbers of 1-100, no strings in it. Will have to take a closer look later and take other comments into consideration. This is all still very new to me but I'm eager to learn and and actively decided to post this very poorly written code here to get "real world" advice from you guys!